# How do I record music as a background for my voice

Tags: audio-recording

I am looking for a program that will record my voice. I also want to add music (a type of slow music), and when I speak I want this music as a background for my voice so my words will still be clear when I speak.

Answer (score 2):

First, make sure you have rights to the music you are recording in the background.

Second, you will need a program to record your voice.  If you want a free program, try [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/).  If you don't mind spending a little money, try [Reaper](http://www.reaper.fm/index.php).  Reaper will allow you to adjust the EQ while you are listening to the recording and give you instant feedback as to what the changes sound like.

Record your voice into your program of choice, then either import or record the music on a separate track.

To get your voice to stand out and put the music in the background, you will use a combination of volume and EQ.  The background music should be adjusted so the level is low enough to not overpower the voice, but also still be able to be heard clearly.  You will also want to use the EQ to slightly lower the level of the frequencies in the same range as the voice.